# How to make sure I get regular ASCII quotes in code examples when using `listings`

Tags: listings, punctuation

So I am writing a book on AWK and when using `listings` code highlighting module, I get the fancy quotes `“ ”` and `‘ ’` instead of the regular ASCII ones `" "` and `' '`. I hate these fancy quotes because when copying code examples from a PDF, they never work in the terminal.

Does anyone know how to make all code examples use only ASCII quotes?

I found out that you can set `\lstset{upquote=true}` and that fixes the single quotes `' '` but the double ones are still broken.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Use a sensible fontencoding. And make a complete example next time so that nobody has to guess what you are doing wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
"a"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Btw: Don't rely to much on copying code from a pdf. Spaces can disappear.

Comment: Did not help in my case, even when placing it immediately above the `lstset` code. Also, what do you do if you need a really sensible font encoding, which supports unicode?

Comment: @Zelphir: Don't use comments to ask new questions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I thought maybe this answer could be improved by not limiting it to `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, that's why I commented.

If I start a new question for such details, it'll get marked as duplicate - people are very quick to do that. Also I don't have an "MWE", so all I'll get is "MWE please!". However, my own setup is quite complex with loads of packages. Any solution for a MWE might not translate into a solution for my specific case. The MWE would have to be my whole template, so that I can be sure.

Comment: So you are too lazy to make a good question and prefer that I spent my time to extend the question to lualatex?