# alltt in PDF to give ASCII 96 (backquote), not U+2018

Tags: fonts, pdftex

When I convert the MWE below to PDF (using `pdflatex`) all occurrences of the backquotes cut-and-paste out of the PDF as U+2018 (a "curly backquote") rather than U+0060 (an ASCII backquote, or backtick character).

Is there any way of giving users of the documentation something that will cut-and-paste in the way I want?  I do need it to be in the `alltt` environment (or similar) to get layout and ability to insert various commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\bq}{\char'140}
\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
`hello`
\bq{}world\bq{}
\end{alltt}

For reference (I need it in the alltt environment or similar): \bq{}hello, world\bq

\end{document}
```

The `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is there because I attempted to follow the advice for the listing package in [How to make sure I get regular ASCII quotes in code examples when using `listings`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17006/how-to-make-sure-i-get-regular-ascii-quotes-in-code-examples-when-using-listing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

```
\`{}
```

If you want to use the T1 encoding, this works:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=10cm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{alltt}

% In T1, the backtick is encoded as "00
\DeclareTextSymbol{\bt}{T1}{"00}

\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
This is a grave accent, or backtick: \bt.  So is this: \`{}.
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

The T1 encoding has [a different layout than ASCII](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf#subsection.A.1).

If you want to use Unicode (whose first 128 characters are the same as ASCII), you can load `fontspec` and then either use `\symbol{"0060}`, or turn off `Ligatures = TeX`.

```
\`{}
```

still works in either OT1, T1 or TU, so it’s your best bet.

Comment: I'm not committed to T1 at all (as per question), that was included because of it seeming to be the right answer for the earlier problem.

Comment: So thanks very much for the short \`{} answer!

Answer (score 6):

You need `upquote` and `textcomp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{alltt,upquote,textcomp}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
`hello`
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

[image]